# Etymology: Dutch Curry

Tags: etymology, food

I've heard of Continental's Dutch Curry and Rice Soup; and I've seen it mentioned here and there... I'm soon to have it later tonight...

But seriously, what makes a Dutch Curry... "Dutch"? It's not served with clogs or tiny windmills, so how does a Dutch curry differ from Indian, Malay or Thai curries? Is it simply just a naming convention or is it something even more in-depth?

I guess, I'm simply after an explanation as to why we call it a *Dutch curry*.

Comment: Sounds more like a question for the Cooking site: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: [*Dutch Curry*](http://m.continental.com.au/product/detail/253960/dutch-curry-rice) sounds quite similar to *Dutch courage*, of which I am familiar but the first is totally foreign to me. Maybe it's a dish made with a lot of cheese? :)

Comment: It basically looks like a "Dutch" soup containing chicken, some vegetables, spices, coconut milk (optional) and curry powder. I couldn't find an explanation why it is called "Dutch" and not Indian for example. It's probably just adaption of a more traditional spicier Indian curry.

Comment: It's listed [here](http://www.cooks.com/rec/search/0,1-0,dutch_curry_rice,FF.html), a list of recipes that can be made in a Dutch oven. So maybe it's related to that term.

Comment: Without knowing what's actually in a "Dutch curry", I'd surmise that it comes from [the Dutch East Indies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_East_Indies#Cuisine) (now Indonesia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as it sounds; it's curry the way the Dutch do it.

Of course, curry isn't indigenous to Holland, but curry had an impact on their cuisine during the colonial period that remains to this day. Indeed, the differences in European cuisines are probably more heavily influenced by their doing different things with different imports from the New World (imagine Italian cuisine with no tomatoes or any North European cuisine without potatoes) and colonial territories as they are differences in ingredients and techniques before that time.

Curry features in cuisine throughout northern Europe, and Europeans have worked further upon the original, especially considering that fresh supplies of the herbs involved were unavailable. Just as the British invented curry powder, so curry ketchup* is popular in Holland and other north European countries and not originally found anywhere the ingredient spices grew.
and while it's origins outside of Europe would be remembered, a British person trying rijsttafel and a Dutch person trying tikka masala would note that they've imported them in different ways.†

That the Dutch had colonial and trading interests meant that not only did they have a source of curry, but also a market for it around the world, and so much of the world had their experience of Indonesian spices brought to them via Dutch kitchens.

So while *curry* isn't originally Dutch, there is by now such a thing as *Dutch curry* and people who have a taste for it, and that is what Continental are claiming to have produced for you in just-add-water form.

---

*Even the word *ketchup* or *catsup* shows a colonial history, being a corruption of Chinese names for fish sauces and later applied to other sauces.

†I assume. Personally I tend not to like anyone's curry, so I have to take that bit on faith.